# Running C++ executable from python script

Tags: python, c++, ros, pepper

we are currently working on robot Pepper, more specific we are trying to prepare Pepper as welcome manager. So when robot gets input from human to go to a certain location, he should start specific dialog for that location and moving to that location. We did the navigation part in ROS and human-interaction part in Python using Python and Naoqi SDK. Now we want to run C++ exe that starts navigation in Python script. What is the simplest way to do that?

Comment: [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), e.g. `subprocess.run(["your_exe", "first_arg"])`. You can also do things like capture stdout/stderr from the subprocess, check return code, wait for subprocess to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relaying M.A's answer here:

> [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html),
> e.g. `subprocess.run(["your_exe", "first_arg"])`.
> You can also do things like capture stdout/stderr from the subprocess,
> check return code, wait for subprocess to complete.